# Adding Background image to UILabel

Tags: ios

How can I add a background image to a UILabel in an iPhone Application. I've tried to do it through IB but with no result.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Try doing it with code:

**Objective-C:**

```
theLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah"]];
```

**Swift:**

```
theLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "blah")!)
```

Or place an `UIImageView` behind the label (not recommended).

---

Update: placing an UIImageView behind a label was not recommended because then you would have to manage two views. But if you must do something that only an UIImageView can do this is still a good approach. I suspect that your app will actually run better this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what i want.

Comment: Excellent and useful feature, 1up! :) But I wonder what Apple was thinking when implementing the image as a backgroundColor. It's utterly counter-intuitive! Even CSS has separate properties for color image of the bg. Maybe it's some legacy from Apple UIs of the past?

Comment: Tested it, and it doesn't support PNG transparency. There could be some trick to it? I did try setting the backgroundColor to clearColor before setting it to the image, just for sports. But no effect, of course.

Comment: To use a transparent PNG you must set the UILabel Opaque property to NO: `[theLabel setOpaque:NO];`

Comment: May I know why it is not recommended to use UIImageView behind the label control? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read somewhere that using `colorWithPatternImage` has performance implication.

Comment: @Azat because the label properties doesn't have a overall effect.For example if you want to hide a label the you will have to additionally hide the UIImageView also.

Comment: @prajul or you add the UILabel as a subview of the UIImageView, then hiding the image view will hide the label too.

Comment: @pixelfreak colorWithPatternImage has some problem issies if it is used for subviews on scrollviews or if you set the backgorund of tableviews

Comment: @IlkerBaltaci yes...i am using colorWithPatternImage with tableview & image is not showing properly...It definitely has some issues...Is there any better way to set images to a label in table view?

Answer (score 18):

if you want that image should be stretched to fill the Label width.
try this code.

```
UILabel *myLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
CGSize imgSize = myLabel.frame.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width,imgSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
```

Comment: it works but for some reason the quality is not as expected. why is that?

Comment: @Esq If you stretch an image it will loose definition and not look as high quality as the original

Comment: How about nine-patch image ? This can fix quality issue?

Comment: About the quality is simple, just use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_, _, 0)` instead (last param is image scale -> 0 = auto).

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2: set the Background image with background color

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(stationNameLabel.frame.size, false, 0.0)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    let components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor)

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, components[0], components[1], components[2], 0.4);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, stationNameLabel.frame.size.width, stationNameLabel.frame.size.height));


    targetImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, stationNameLabel.frame.size.width, stationNameLabel.frame.size.height))
    let resultImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: resultImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let messageBackgroundView = UIImageView()
        messageBackgroundView.image = UIImage(named: "chat-background")
        if messageBackgroundView.superview != lblChatdata.superview {
            lblChatdata.superview!.insertSubview(messageBackgroundView, belowSubview: lblChatdata)
            messageBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                messageBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblChatdata.leadingAnchor),
                messageBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblChatdata.trailingAnchor),
                messageBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblChatdata.topAnchor),
                messageBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblChatdata.bottomAnchor),
                ])
            messageBackgroundView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

@pixelfreak, your right. UIColor instance with color image pattern has serious performance issues when assigning it to backroundcolor

```
cell.cellLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)
```