# How to set a background image to label

Tags: ios, uilabel

I want to display a number on image like badge of size 30*28, which is placed upon button image,

I have an badge image to set up on the top of button image..
on top of badge image I should able to display text or number and my badge size is 30*28.

so, for this to achieve I want to set a label on top of my button image and so I want to set label background to some image called badge image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't add a background image to a UILabel, but you can add a UIImageView as a subview to a UILabel. Make sure the UILabel has `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` for transparency.

E.g.

```
UIImageView *labelBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] 
    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mybg.png"]];
[myLabel addSubview:labelBackground];
[labelBackground release];
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Should work. Untested.

Comment: but the label text is not seen.Only the image is appearing.

Comment: Wrong answer, background images are addable to uilabels ! it's not engcouraged to add a UIImage as a subview to give a "background" effect.

Comment: Feel free to use the wording "outdated answer" as the answer was correct 2 years ago when it was posted. ;) That said, if people want backwards compatibility with older iOS:es they might still find this answer useful.

Comment: This code will work.. just remember to send the subview to back. [myLabel sendSubviewToBack:labelBackground];

Answer (score 11):

found this in stack overflow itself as the above code just gives the background without the label

was useful for me 
so sharing

```
theLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah"]];
```

See: [Adding Background image to UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037930/1243762)

Answer (score 1):

**To make the image fit in your** *UIview*, **try this code**

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNameHere"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.labelName.frame.size);
[backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.labelName.frame.size.width, self.labelName.frame.size.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.labelName.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
```