# It is Possible to set background image for a label

Tags: swift

I want to set background image for a label in my project but i dont know for how to set, please say it is possible or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Background image to UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037902/adding-background-image-to-uilabel)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
yourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "backgroundImage")!)
```

Comment: It does repeat the pattern if image is small, can we fit exact 1 preview of image in background ?

Answer (score 3):

The UILabel control does not have `background image` or `image` property.

You can set image to `UILabel` using `backgroundColor` property as shown below :

```
cell.lblNumber!.text = ""  
cell.lblNumber!.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "OK")!)
```

Set the text to empty since it will display image and text on top of it.

[image: Screenshot for solution]

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer..@Jayprakash Dubey