# Swift: Make an image in background of label

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background, label

I want to put label into an image that is a red rectangle with corner radius (in condition that the image size must to be equal or slightly higher than the label one). For that I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037902/adding-background-image-to-uilabel). I tested this:

```
theLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "blah")!)
```

But I have problems with the image size. So I tested the second answer:

```
UILabel *myLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
CGSize imgSize = myLabel.frame.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width,imgSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
```

Having the last version of Xcode (Xcode 8.0) the `CGRectMake` is unavailable.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why don't you just use `UIImageView` and `UILabel` with the same frames?

Comment: How about creating the UIImageView first and set the image you want on it. Then add the label as its subview.

Comment: because of the UIImageView size. My image is sometimes bigger than the text inside it.

Comment: now you change your mind. so you want the image slightly smaller than text label i that you want?

Comment: not smaller but the same size or slightly bigger because my image is a red rectangle with corner radius

Comment: as you mentioned label and image size must be same.. why dont you apply a border to your label is still same ?

Comment: check my update.let me know what you thing....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this code:**  Tested in Swift 3.

**Answer 1:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:imageView.frame.width , height:imageView.frame.height)
    label.text = "Some Title"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .yellow
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-medium", size: CGFloat(20))
    imageView.addSubview(label)
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Answer 2:** **Updated**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:imageView.frame.width , height:imageView.frame.height)
    label.text = "Some Title"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .yellow
    label.layer.borderColor  = UIColor.red.cgColor
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    label.layer.masksToBounds = true
    label.layer.borderWidth = 5
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-medium", size: CGFloat(26))

    imageView.addSubview(label)
}
```

**Note:** You need to workout the image size and label font size.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I think that in this case the label frame size is set to the image one, but what I want is that the image size be similar to the label one

Comment: Thanks for the update but will the image be resized in function of the text inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Your objective c code in question is changed into swift 3.0

```
var myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))

var img = UIImage(named:"a")

var imgSize : CGSize =  myLabel.frame.size

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))

image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))

let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: newImage)
```