# UILabel rendering in to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, edit

Am trying to place `UILabel` in to `UIImage`, i am able to change the label frame width and height
But am unable to change X and Y values someone please help me to change the x and y values.

This is the way i call the method

```
self.imfFront.image = generateImageWithText(text: "Hello World !")
```

**Method goes here**

```
func generateImageWithText(text: String) -> UIImage
{
    let image = UIImage(named:"img_forest")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:image.size.width, height:image.size.height)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:50, y:50, width:image.size.width-50, height:image.size.height-50))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.text = text

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
    imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    label.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return imageWithText!
}
```

below is the reference image

[image: This is the screenshot how uilabel is rendre in to uiimage]

Comment: what the OP you expect

Comment: I want to place UILabel or UITextview in to UIImage

Comment: i got it bro, in center of entire frame of uiimageview

Comment: where you called this `generateImageWithText` in viewdidlaod or else

Comment: in viewdidload()

Comment: try in viewwillappear or viewdidappear once

Comment: It did not work

Comment: If possible please see the application in appstore InkCards i want to implement like that text edit in image, I dont know how they are doing

Comment: is this possible to attach the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166579/discussion-between-mahesh-m-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379082/swift-make-an-image-in-background-of-label/40379453#40379453

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would specify a `labelRect` like so:

```
let labelRect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: image.size.width - 100, height: image.size.height / 16)
let label = UILabel(frame: labelRect)
```

and instead of:

```
label.layer.render...
```

you would write:

```
label.drawHierarchy(in: labelRect, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

then the resulting image shown in an UIImageView would look like this:

[image: resulting image shown in UIImageView]

Any changes to the x- or y-value of labelRect would move the label around.

One remark: you should keep in mind that you are drawing on an image, so the actual size of the label font is dependent on the resolution of the image. Depending on your requirements, this may or may not be your intention.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz2d uses a different co-ordinate system, where the origin is in the lower left corner. So instead of render you can draw it...

```
let rect = imageView.bounds.size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect)
imageView.draw(imageView.bounds.size)
label.draw(rect)

//    imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
//     label.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

let imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: nop, it did not worked. Plus it ate up the label background colour too.